# Looping generating a list of dates (days) beween multiple start and end dates

Tags: excel, vba

i have found some VBA codes/XLS formulas, but after many attempts i failed to replicate for my purpose. Could you please help me ?

I have table with name, startdate, enddate, type of absence. This includes about 1000 rows, each row includes all 4 columns of data, values can be duplicities. Dates are formatted as dates.
For each row, i need to generate list of days(dates) betweet start and end date - all dates from all rows has to be in one column. In the best way aslo to assign to list of days name&absence type to next columns.
I need to do it in loop for all rows in column incl. vlaue (the @ rows may vary from month to month).
Using O365 desktop

Can you please help me ? Thank you so much in advanced

Coredata:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuSdX.png)

Desired output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDDsk.png)

Tried codes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcvUp.png)

Excel formula:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i38Vu.png)

Comment: The problem with putting all those links to images is that we can't copy the data, code or formulas to set up a test environment to help you.  

Some of us (me included) cannot access file download sites whilst at work so, if I was inclined, I would need to dig out a personal device to go look at your stuff.  That's too much bother for most, so you are limiting even further the number of people who can help you.

Just put the information into the body of your question.

Comment: Not to mention, unless it's just my machine playing up - the images of 'Tried codes' and 'Excel Formula' are so small you only see a few words anyway.

Comment: The images linked are truncated when I try to display them.

Answer (score 0):

- Load data into an array

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim arrRes, iR As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long, oSht As Worksheet
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify as needed
    Set rngData = oSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ' Load data
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' Count output rows
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        If IsDate(arrData(i, 4)) And IsDate(arrData(i, 3)) Then
            iR = iR + arrData(i, 4) - arrData(i, 3) + 1
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim arrRes(1 To iR, 2)
    iR = 0
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        If IsDate(arrData(i, 4)) And IsDate(arrData(i, 3)) Then
            For j = arrData(i, 3) To arrData(i, 4)
                iR = iR + 1
                arrRes(iR, 0) = j
                arrRes(iR, 1) = arrData(i, 2)
                arrRes(iR, 2) = arrData(i, 5)
            Next
        End If
    Next i
    ' Write data to a new sheet
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A1:C1") = Array("Output Dates", "Name", "Type")
    Range("A2").Resize(iR, 3).Value = arrRes
    Columns(1).NumberFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144111)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144111)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

[image]